# Why do '::' and '->' work (sort of) interchangeably when calling methods from Perl modules?

Tags: perl, oop, module

I keep getting `::` confused with `->` when calling subroutines from modules. I know that `::` is more related to paths and where the module/subroutine is and `->` is used for objects, but I don't really understand why I can seemingly interchange both and it not come up with immediate errors.
I have perl modules which are part of a larger package, e.g. `FullProgram::Part1`

I'm just about getting to grips with modules, but still am on wobbly grounds when it comes to Perl objects, but I've been accidentally doing this:

```
FullProgram::Part1::subroutine1();
```

instead of

```
FullProgram::Part1->subroutine1();
```

so when I've been passing a hash ref to subroutine1 and been careful about using `$class/$self` to deal with the object reference and accidentally use `::` I end up pulling my hair out wondering why  my hash ref seems to disappear. I have learnt my lesson, but would really like an explanation of the difference. I have read the perldocs and various websites on these but I haven't seen any comparisons between the two (quite hard to google...) 
All help appreciated - always good to understand what I'm doing!

Comment: some good answers, hard to choose, but thanks - definitely cleared things up!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
FullProgram::Part1::subroutine1();
```

calls the subroutine `subroutine1` of the package `FullProgram::Part1` with an empty parameter list while

```
FullProgram::Part1->subroutine1();
```

calls the same subroutine with the package name as the first argument (note that it gets a little bit more complex when you're subclassing). This syntax is used by constructor methods that need the class name for building objects of subclasses like

```
sub new {
    my ($class, @args) = @_;
    ...
    return bless $thing, $class;
}
```

FYI: in Perl OO you see `$object->method(@args)` which calls `Class::method` with the object (a blessed reference) as the first argument instead of the package/class name. In a method like this, the subroutine could work like this:

```
sub method {
    my ($self, $foo, $bar) = @_;
    $self->do_something_with($bar);
    # ...
}
```

which will call the subroutine `do_something_with` with the object as first argument again followed by the value of `$bar` which was the second list element you originally passed to `method` in `@args`. That way the object itself doesn't get lost.

For more informations about how the inheritance tree becomes important when calling methods, please see [ikegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13479403/1184510)!

Comment: `$object->method(@args)` doesn't "just calls Class::method". It calls the first method named `method` found in the inheritance tree.

Comment: Tried to mention that topic without making my answer too complex and removed the "just". Thanks, @ikegami!

Answer (score 9):

There's no inherent difference between a vanilla sub and one's that's a method. It's all in how you call it.

---

```
Class::foo('a');
```

This will call `Class::foo`. If `Class::foo` doesn't exist, the inheritance tree will not be checked. `Class::foo` will be passed only the provided arguments (`'a'`).

It's roughly the same as: `my $sub = \&Class::foo; $sub->('a');`

---

```
Class->foo('a');
```

This will call `Class::foo`, or `foo` in one of its base classes if `Class::foo` doesn't exist. The invocant (what's on the left of the `->`) will be passed as an argument.

It's roughly the same as: `my $sub = Class->can('foo'); $sub->('Class', 'a');`

Answer (score 5):

Use both!

```
use Module::Two;

Module::Two::->class_method();
```

Note that this works but also protects you against an ambiguity there; the simple

```
Module::Two->class_method();
```

will be interpreted as:

```
Module::Two()->class_method();
```

(calling the subroutine Two in Module and trying to call class_method on its return value - likely resulting in a runtime error or calling a class or instance method in some completely different class) *if* there happens to be a sub Two in Module - something that you shouldn't depend on one way or the other, since it's not any of *your* code's business what is in Module.

Comment: The parsing ambiguity expressed here is one of my "favorite" things about Perl.  The fact that the workaround is so ugly makes me sad.

Comment: @darch: I don't think it's ugly.  What do you think of `"Module::Two"->class_method()`?

Answer (score 0):

Historically, Perl dont had any OO. And functions from packages called with `FullProgram::Part1::subroutine1();` sytax. Or even before with `FullProgram'Part1'subroutine1();` syntax(deprecated).

Later, they implemented OOP with `->` sign, but dont changed too much actually. `FullProgram::Part1->subroutine1();` calls `subroutine1` and `FullProgram::Part1` goes as 1st parameter. you can see usage of this when you create an object: `my $cgi = CGI->new()`. Now, when you call a method from this object, left part also goes as first parameter to function: `$cgi->param('')`. Thats how `param` gets object he called from (usually named `$self`). Thats it. `->` is hack for OOP. So as a result Perl does not have classes(packages work as them) but does have objects("objects" hacks too - they are blessed scalars).

Offtop: Also you can call with `my $cgi = new CGI;` syntax. This is same as `CGI->new`. Same when you say `print STDOUT "text\n";`. Yeah, just just calling `IOHandle::print()`.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `->` causes perl to look up the inheritance tree (yet another hack via `@ISA`).